# Xdebug don't stop in the breakpoints

Tags: magento2.2.6, xdebug

I try to debug my magento2 project with xdebug php 7.1 and nginx. I have differents breakpoints in app/code/Extension/Module and doesn't stop in any one.

Just stop if I have the option "Break at the first line" in the index.php but in my breakpoints don't work...

I'm developing locally

My php.ini configuration is the next:

```
;XDEBUG
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

PHPINFO:
[image]

PHPSTORM:
[image]
[image]